# Visual Studio Code (VSC) with C# -- where is "go to definition" or "find all references?"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code with C#.  In the image below, you will see that there is no "go to definition" or "find all references" option.  I come from a js background, and I use these *religiously*.  I honestly can't imagine developing without it.  How do I enable these things?  Is there some sort of plugin that I am missing?

If you can help me out here, then I would be *extremely* grateful.  Thank you in advanced.

[image]

Comment: Did you install the [C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) extension?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I did.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] then. Specifically, what does your project directory look like? What are the steps you took to reach the state that you showed in the screenshot? Please describe each of your steps in detail, starting with how you have created your project.

Comment: I can see "Go To Defination" in my VS Code. I have installed "C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)" and "CS-Script - VSCode Extension"

Comment: Note that if you opened a _folder_ with a .csproj or .sln file in it, it should work. Did you happen to open a single file?

Comment: @Amit Verma, I installed CS-Script and now the options are present!  However, they do not do anything unfortunately

Comment: @Swepper To be fair, and you can certainly fault me for not mentioning this earlier, I am using this with Unity.  I didn't want to mention this earlier because I was hoping for a general answer that could reveal how these  UI options work internally.  But I am definately going to be looking for a .csproj in the directory Unity is working in.

Comment: I've never used VSCode with Unity before, but I know that Unity does a lot of things differently. From a quick search, I found [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unity.unity-debug). See if you can work out how to use it.

Comment: @Sweeper It looks like Unity automatically opesn a folder with a .sln file.  Unity might have produced a bad file.  So in other words, it's possible that this is a bug with Unity.

Comment: @Sweeper Ah, I already have that installed.  Thanks for the recommendation however.

Comment: @Sweeper Well, I've been searching in the Unity forums for a while now looking for an answer.  I think most people who use Unity use Visual Studio.  Personally, I despise Visual Studio; to me, it's just a more clunky, uglier version of VSC with terrible UX.  But if I have to use it, then I will.  Thanks for your help.  <3

Comment: I also had the same issue with dotnet core. after I install CS-Script and Mono debugger it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple projects you may need a solution file (.sln) and all your projects should be added to it.

Create the sln file:

```
>dotnet new sln -n my.sln
```

Add a project to it:

```
>dotnet sln add src/MyProj/MyProj.csproj
```

Then in VS Code, restart the .NET language server:

1. Open the command pallette (Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + P)
2. Select ".NET: Restart Language Server"